# jquery dynamic adding hidden field

Tags: jquery

```
$().ready(function() 
  {
  $("#add").click(function() 
    {
    var vals = $("#txtaddfeature").val();
    if(vals !='')
      $('#FeatureLists').prepend('<option value="' + vals + '" selected="selected">' + vals + '</option>');
    $('#txtaddfeature').val('');
    });
  });
```

Ok after adding the value to the select list as above

```
$('#FeatureLists').prepend('<option value="' + vals + '" selected="selected">' + vals + '</option>');
```

I want to create a dynamic hidden field with id=vals defined above and set it value to value entered in the textbox . how can i do that

Comment: Off topic - What version of jQuery are you using? `$().ready(...)` probably shouldn't be used if you have jQuery 1.4 since `$()` no longer returns a jQuery object with the `document`. Instead, do `$(document).ready(...)`, or just `$(function() {...})`.

Comment: ok thx I will review my code and change it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I couldn't tell exactly what you wanted. It seems like you want both the `ID` and the `value` of the new hidden `input` to be the value of `vals`. Is that right?

```
var $hiddenInput = $('<input/>',{type:'hidden',id:vals,value:vals});
```

Then you would append it wherever you want.

```
$hiddenInput.appendTo(selector);
```

**EDIT:**

For clarification, `selector` is the reference to the element where you want to append your new input.

If you want to append it to the body tag, do:

```
$hiddenInput.appendTo('body');
```

If you want to append it to an element with the class `someClass`, do:

```
$hiddenInput.appendTo('.someClass');
```

Comment: $hiddenInput.appendTo(selector); , what is the selector here

Comment: Sorry, `selector` is simply the element where you want to append the input. For example, if you typed 'body', it would append the hidden input to the body. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Why the '$' on hiddenInput?

Answer (score 2):

I would check to see if it was on the page first, then add.

```
function SetHiddenInput(val)
{
    var $txtaddfeaturehidden == $("#txtaddfeaturehidden");

    if ($txtaddfeaturehidden.length == 0)
    {
        $("input").attr({
            id : "txtaddfeaturehidden", 
            type : "hidden",
            value : $('#txtaddfeature').val()
        }).after('#txtaddfeature');
    }
    else $txtaddfeaturehidden.val(val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
$("input").attr("type", 'hidden').val($('#txtaddfeature').val()).appendTo('selector_here');
```